# pacman -S mono-complete ~ error: target not found: mono-complete | How can I get this to install? I'm using arch linux

Tags: mono, archlinux

When I try to install mono-complete, it says that the target is not found.

I've tried using just mono, but when I do that, it says that the command is not found.  I'm using Arch Linux on an OVH VPS.

`pacman -S mono-complete`
This Returns:
`error: target not found: mono-complete`

I'm trying to install this so that I can access mono commands, but I cannot seem to get it installed.

Comment: Target is not found. `mono-complete` is not in the official repositories, so you don't install it with pacman. If it is in the AUR you can look into installing it with another tool.

Comment: It seems your original issue is failure to install "mono" package. Did you see any errors when you run `pacman -S mono`?

Answer (score 2):

Install mono package

`sudo pacman -S mono`